# How many actions can you take per turn?

Tags: catan

In Settlers of Catan can you conduct multiple transactions on your turn?

You roll, collect your resource cards, and then:

Can you build a road and a settlement?
Can you build a road and do a trade with another opponent?
Can you do a trade and buy a resource card?

We have been playing one transaction per turn but not sure what the rules are pertaining to this.

Answer (score 18):

Yes, from the [turn overview](http://www.catan.com/files/downloads/settlers_of_catan_turn_overview.pdf) of the [game rules](http://www.catan.com/service/game-rules):

> You may build as long as your resource supply allows for it.

Also, the Combined Trade/Build Phase section of the [Almanac](http://www.catan.com/files/downloads/soc_rv_rules_091907.pdf) states that

> After rolling for resource production, you can trade and build in any order. Naturally, you can trade, build, trade again and build again.

You are restricted to playing only one Development Card, however, and you cannot play a Development Card that you bought on your current turn.

Comment: Is there any rule in the newer edition rules that states whether or not a player can build a settlement on a port, then use that port to trade for some more resources. This technically would be building and trading, and if there wasn't anymore order to the two there shouldn't be a problem. Or is there a rule much like the Development Cards that prevents immediate usage?

Comment: @JaysonSmith Yes, you can. The Combined Trade/Build Phase section of the Almanac (linked in my answer) also says "You can even use a harbor on the same turn as you build a settlement there."

Comment: That combined trade/build is a suggestion.  The rules as stated, and as usually enforced in tournaments, strictly require trading before building.

Answer (score 5):

You CAN conduct multiple actions or transactions. If you have enough cards and the right conditions, you could buy several different settlements, roads and so forth. What you are limited on is the following:

1. Actions HAVE to be done in sequences. The stages of your turn is broken into three general phases---Roll the dice/Collect Resources, Trade (both from a port, the bank (4:1), or with other players), and Buy/Build. As long as you perform those actions like that, you could take as many as you'd like. (Note: Playing a Development Card is not considered a phase, as it can be played during any part of your turn...even before you roll the dice.)
2. You can only play ONE development card per turn. Also, the Development Card you are playing can not be purchase during that same turn you 'play' the card. So you would have to wait one turn to play it. This also means if you bought 3 cards in one turn, you would have to use your next 3 turns to play them (if you chose to play them as fast as possible). The only exception to the 'wait a turn' rule, is with a Development Card that gave you a Victory Point (e.g. Governor's House). Yet, even the Victory Point cards seem to have to comply to the 'no more than one card can be played per turn'.
3. You are limited on buyings/building more than the alloted number of pieces. For instance, if you already have 5 Settlements built you could not build another one, until one is upgraded to a City, because the pieces intentionally limit this (though my set came with 10 Red Settlements as an error, so make sure you start the game with the right numbers: 5 Settlements, 4 Cities, and 15 Roads for the basic set).

Comment: I think more recent editions allow build and trade in any order.